# How to create JSON using MQTT javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, mqtt, thingsboard

I am trying to publish few real time values using MQTT javascript. Here below I need set proper JSON format values.
Here I can send only one value for all buses but I need to send Seperate buses seperate values. How to do that.

**My Current Code:**

```
var data = {
    Buses: "BusA", "BusB", "BusC",
    Speed: BusA_minspeed + (BusA_maxspeed - BusA_minspeed) * Math.random(), // It should be use seperate values seperate Buses
    FL: BusA_minfl + (BusA_maxfl - BusA_minfl) * Math.random()
};
```

**My Expectations:**

```
Buses  Speed FL
BusA    123  80
BusB    231  40
BusC    124  50
```

**My Publishing Part**

```
function publishTelemetry() {
    data.Speed = genNextValue(data.Speed, BusA_minspeed, BusA_maxspeed);
    data.FL = genNextValue(data.Fl, BusA_minfl, BusA_maxfl);
    client.publish('v1/devices/me/telemetry', JSON.stringify(data));
}

function genNextValue(prevValue, min, max) {
    var value = prevValue + ((max - min) * (Math.random() - 0.5)) * 0.03;
    value = Math.max(min, Math.min(max, value));
    return Math.round(value * 10) / 10;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From your expectation I see you should have a JSON structure like this

`data` has a property `Buses` which is an array of following object

```
{
  Name: BUS_NAME,
  Speed: BUSS_SPEED,
  FL: YOUR_FL
}
```

**JSON**

```
var data = {
  Buses: [{ 
    Name: 'BusA'
    Speed: BusA_minspeed + (BusA_maxspeed - BusA_minspeed) * Math.random(), // It should be use seperate values seperate Buses
    FL: BusA_minfl + (BusA_maxfl - BusA_minfl) * Math.random()
  },{
    Name: 'BusB'
    Speed: BusB_minspeed + (BusB_maxspeed - BusB_minspeed) * Math.random(), // It should be use seperate values seperate Buses
    FL: BusB_minfl + (BusB_maxfl - BusB_minfl) * Math.random()
  },{
    Name: 'BusC'
    Speed: BusC_minspeed + (BusC_maxspeed - BusC_minspeed) * Math.random(), // It should be use seperate values seperate Buses
    FL: BusC_minfl + (BusC_maxfl - BusC_minfl) * Math.random()
  }] 
}
```

If you have above structure of JSON you can send separate data as follows

Use the follwing function and pass the `busName` to get the object of a perticular bus

```
function getBusData(busName){
   return data.buses.filter(function(bus){
      return bus.Name == busName;
  })[0];
}
```

**USAGE**

```
 var busA_data = getBusData('BusA');
```

Now, use your busA_data which should contain

```
{ 
    Name: 'BusA'
    Speed: 123,
    FL: 80
}
```

To publish you need to convert JSON to string using `JSON.stringify` and publish as follows

`client.publish(YOUR_BROKER, JSON.stringify(busA_data));`

and You need to do the opposite in .on('message', fn), e.g.

```
client.on('message', function (topic, payload) {
  const obj = JSON.parse(payload.toString()) // payload is your JSON as string
})
```

Comment: Thank you @Nadir Laskar. How can I publish all the values?

Comment: I need to get all the bus speeds and FL. Like above mentioned expectation table and same time I am generating random values for all the bus speed and FL. Could you please edit above answer.

Comment: could you please send your email ID?

Comment: Share you email, I will ping you.